# blackberry trying to create a count down timer and exception gets thrown when text is updated

Tags: blackberry, timer

I’m trying to create a count down timer. I user a `Timer` object that is given a `timertask`.  I have a label field called `mTimerDisplay` that is a static member of a class I call `cGlobols`.

On the `run` method, that gets called by the timer, can change the color of the label fine:

```
cGlobals.mTimerDisplay.setBackground(
    BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xff0000));
```

When I add the following line:

```
cGlobals.mTimerDisplay.setText("Hi");
```

it throws a `IllegalStateException`:
I looked this up and it says

> Signals that a method has been invoked
>   at an illegal or inappropriate time.
>   In other words, the Java environment
>   or Java application is not in an
>   appropriate state for the requested
>   operation.,

Does this mean I cannot do this operation on the thread, but if so why can I change the color? If I cannot do this on the timer thread, is there another way to do this?

Comment: In java, style calls for class names to begin with a capital letter.  Also, if I understand the meaning of your class, I think you've misspelled "globals".   So naming your class 'CGlobals' would be an improvement on conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A worker thread cannot update the UI without attaining the event thread. Wrap the setText() invocation in a synchronized block, and use Application.getEventLock() to attain this lock.